# web crawler not working properly

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, web-crawler

I have created a webcrawler in python 2.7 and i am using mysqldb to insert data into database.

### I have executed each function as a different script for different webpages, but after i put them into a single file as functions, the program shows error;

(After entering seed page and depth)

---

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chetan\Desktop\webCrawler.py", line 207, in 
    mainFunc(depth,url)

File "C:\Users\Chetan\Desktop\webCrawler.py", line 194, in mainFunc
    lst=perPage(url)

File "C:\Users\Chetan\Desktop\webCrawler.py", line 186, in perPage
    filterContent(url,page)

File "C:\Users\Chetan\Desktop\webCrawler.py", line 149, in filterContent
    cursor.execute(sql)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py", line 202, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler

```
raise errorclass, errorvalue
```

ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near \'s and specials." />\n

---

I can't seem to find any problem. Here is the code;

```
def metaContent(page,url):#EXTRACTS META TAG CONTENT
    lst=[]
    while page.find("<meta")!=-1:
            start_link=page.find("<meta")
            page=page[start_link:]
            start_link=page.find("content=")
            start_quote=page.find('"',start_link)
            end_quote=page.find('"',start_quote+1)
            metaTag=page[start_quote+1:end_quote]
            page=page[end_quote:]
            lst.append(metaTag)

    #ENTER DATA INTO DB
    i,j=0,0
    while i<len(lst):
        sql = "INSERT INTO META(URL, \
               KEYWORD) \
               VALUES ('%s','%s')" % \
               (url,lst[i])
        cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()

def filterContent(page,url):#FILTERS THE CONTENT OF THE REMAINING PORTION
    phrase = ['to','a','an','the',"i'm",\
        'for','from','that','their',\
        'i','my','your','you','mine',\
        'we','okay','yes','no','as',\
        'if','but','why','can','now',\
        'are','is','also']

    #CALLS FUNC TO REMOVE HTML TAGS
    page = strip_tags(page)

    #CONVERT TO LOWERCASE
    page = page.lower()

    #REMOVES WHITESPACES
    page = page.split()
    page = " ".join(page)

    #REMOVES IDENTICAL WORDS AND COMMON WORDS
    page = set(page.split())
    page.difference_update(phrase)

    #CONVERTS FROM SET TO LIST
    lst = list(page)

    #ENTER DATA INTO DB
    i,j=0,0
    while i<len(lst):
        sql = "INSERT INTO WORDS(URL, \
               KEYWORD) \
               VALUES ('%s','%s')" % \
               (url,lst[i])
        cursor.execute(sql)
    db.commit()


#<6>
def perPage(url):#CALLS ALL THE FUNCTIONS
    page=pageContent(url)

    #REMOVES CONTENT BETWEEN SCRIPT TAGS
    flg=0
    while page.find("<script",flg)!=-1:
            start=page.find("<script",flg)
            end=page.find("</script>",flg)
            end=end+9
            i,k=0,end-start
            page=list(page)
            while i<k:
                    page.pop(start)
                    i=i+1
            page=''.join(page)
            flg=start
    #REMOVES CONTENT BETWEEN STYLE TAGS
    flg=0
    while page.find("<script",flg)!=-1:
            start=page.find("<style",flg)
            end=page.find("</style>",flg)
            end=end+9
            i,k=0,end-start
            page=list(page)
            while i<k:
                    page.pop(start)
                    i=i+1
            page=''.join(page)
            flg=start

    metaContent(url,page)
    lst=linksExt(url,page)
    filterContent(url,page)
    return lst#CHECK WEATHER NEEDED OR NOT


#<7>
crawled=[]
def mainFunc(depth,url):#FOR THE DEPTH MANIPULATION
    if (depth):
        lst=perPage(url)
        crawled.append(url)
        i=0
        if (depth-1):
            while i<len(lst):
                if url[i] not in crawled:
                    mainFunc(depth-1,url[i])
                i+=1

#CALLING MAIN FUNCTION
mainFunc(depth,url)
```

Please mention any error, especially in depth manipulation function( mainFunc()). Anything regarding improving the crawler would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely sql error, your quotes are not being escaped.

Instead of this

```
sql = "INSERT INTO META(URL, \
           KEYWORD) \
           VALUES ('%s','%s')" % \
           (url,lst[i])
cursor.execute(sql)
```

and this

```
sql = "INSERT INTO WORDS(URL, \
           KEYWORD) \
           VALUES ('%s','%s')" % \
           (url,lst[i])
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Try this

```
sql = "INSERT INTO WORDS(URL, \
           KEYWORD) \
           VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (url, lst[i]))
```

and this

```
sql = "INSERT INTO META(URL, \
           KEYWORD) \
           VALUES (%s, %s)"
cursor.execute(sql, (url, lst[i]))
```

Also you are using while but not incrementing i, instead you can use this

```
for keyword in lst:
    sql = "INSERT INTO META(URL, \
           KEYWORD) \
           VALUES (%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (url, keyword))
```

Comment: you are using while i<len(lst) but not incrementing i anywhere, try above code in both

Comment: try new one i have removed to quotes which is unnecessary by the way using prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

In the recursive call of `mainFunc` you are calling `main` function,

```
main(depth-1,url[i])
```

There is no `main` function in your code.

change it to,

```
mainFunc(depth-1,url[i])
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Though there is an edit i made to the question. Please help if possible.:)